# How can I use the `close_account` function properly in order to close an Associated Token Account?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to close an Associated Token Account (ATA) from inside a program. The ATA belongs to the program. I found a function called `close_account`, but I haven't figured out how to use it properly. I'm using Anchor.

The desired flow of my program is:

1. Send a token from the program ATA to the user ATA (I've done this successfully)
2. Close the program ATA that was used for the token

This is what the implementation of `close_account` looks like:

```
pub fn close_account<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info>(
    ctx: CpiContext<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, CloseAccount<'info>>,
) -> Result<()> {
    let ix = spl_token::instruction::close_account(
        &spl_token::ID,
        ctx.accounts.account.key,
        ctx.accounts.destination.key,
        ctx.accounts.authority.key,
        &[], // TODO: support multisig
    )?;
    solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.account.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.destination.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.authority.clone(),
        ],
        ctx.signer_seeds,
    )
    .map_err(Into::into)
}
```

The `CloseAccount` struct looks as follows:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CloseAccount<'info> {
    pub account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub destination: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

(I assume) the account is the ATA and the authority is my program - but what is the **destination** in this context? Why would closing an account need a destination and which account should I use as the destination account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the destination in this context? Why would closing an account need a destination and which account should I use as the destination account?

Since token accounts are like any other account in Solana, they must have enough SOL to cover the minimum balance requirement.  When closing an account, you must send that SOL somewhere else, hence the "destination".  The best option is to use a wallet / SOL account that is only used for SOL and nothing else.

More info at https://spl.solana.com/token#closing-accounts